# Will hql give you compile time errors?

Tags: nhibernate

Will hql give you compile time errors like criteria query?

I remember hearing that one of the methods doesn't (besides raw SQL).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  Since HQL is essentially a string, you need an IDE to parse it and figure out if you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No query build in Hibernate, neither HQLs nor Critieras, will produce compile time errors. Nevertheless you can use the NamedQuery annotation to declare your static HQL queries in a static way. This will provide caching and validity checks when starting your application because hibernate's session factory will read all NamedQueries on first startup.

Answer (score 0):

HQL wil not give you compile time errors, as it is only treated as a string at compile time.
What do you mean with 'like criteria query'?

Answer (score 0):

Criteria queries *may not* give you compile time errors, something like this will error

```
ICriteria crit = sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat));
crit.SetMaxResults("50"); /* wrong parameter type */
List cats = crit.List();
```

Something like this will not

```
IList cats = sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat))
.Add( Expression.Like("Naem", "Fritz%") ) /* misspelled property */
.Add( Expression.Between("Weight", minWeight, maxWeight) )
.List();
```